# Open dialog on already opened dialog MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, dialog

I watched a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqKaV4d4PXg) about creating a DialogService that will take care of opening dialogs in MVVM. Since DialogService constructor takes owner (Window type) as parameter, it is easy to create dialogService in MainWindow. Just create a View and a ViewModel for MainWindow separately in App.xaml.cs and connect all thing. But the problem is how do I create a dialogService in dialog that is opened from the MainWindow (to open more dialogs from that dialog) since I cannot get the View instance of the dialog that is opened from MainWindowViewModel. Here's a method for showing that dialog.

```
private void ShowAdministrationDialog()
{
        AdministrationDialogViewModel viewModel = new AdministrationDialogViewModel(this.context);
        dialogService.ShowDialog(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the video does not support your use case. The dialog service seems to be a singleton, only capable of opening dialogs where main window is the owner. For many circumstances that is probably fine, for others, as yours, it simply doesn't work.

I've created a NuGet package called MvvmDialogs capable of opening dialogs in all possible circumstances. You can browse the code on GitHub. I've solved the problem by introducing an attached property that acts as the bridge between views and view models. Thus I am always able to jump from a view model to its view, and from the view traverse up the logical UI tree until I reach the owning window.

This is only one solution to the problem, I am sure you can find another if you wish to build your own dialog service. If you don't, there is always MvvmDialogs :D

Comment: Is there a way to reduce dialog's owner Window opacity while dialog is displayed and then switch it back to normal when it's closed?

Comment: Do you mean in MvvmDialogs or in the dialog service you are implementing yourself? There is no support for it in MvvmDialogs at the current point, but one could think of a solution where the dialog service exposes events describing opened and closed dialogs, and you would be able to hook into those events to update the window opacity. Create an issue if this is something you would find useful, and we can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the package! I posted an issue. Also, is this package free to use if my project is for commercial uses?

Comment: Absolutely. The code is licensed under Apache License 2.0 and will grant you the permissions to use in commercial applications. But please read up on Apache License 2.0 before you create a dependency towards the package.

Answer (score 0):

Fould a way to solve this, but I'm not sure if it breaks MVVM, so FantasticFiasco's solution is probably better. In DialogService class separate method ShowDialog into 2 methods - PrepareDialog and ShowDialog

PrepareDialog:

```
public void PrepareDialog<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel) where TViewModel : IDialogRequestClose
    {
        // Finds a ViewType from Mappings
        Type viewType = Mappings[typeof(TViewModel)];

        // Creates a View instance
        IDialog dialog = (IDialog)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType);

        // Adds an event on dialog close request
        EventHandler<DialogCloseRequestedEventArgs> handler = null;
        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Dispatch handler
            viewModel.CloseRequested -= handler;

            // Reset owner's opacity
            dialog.Owner.Opacity = 1;

            // Returns a result if exists
            if (e.DialogResult.HasValue)
            {
                dialog.DialogResult = e.DialogResult;
            }
            else
            {
                dialog.Close();
            }
        };

        dialog.DataContext = viewModel;
        dialog.Owner = owner;
        dialog.Owner.Opacity = 0.5;

        // Adds handler for close request
        viewModel.CloseRequested += handler;

        // Initializes a dialog service in opening dialog's ViewModel if supports it
        IViewModelDialogService viewModelDialogService = viewModel as IViewModelDialogService;
        if (viewModelDialogService != null)
        {
            viewModelDialogService.DialogService = new DialogService((Window)dialog);
        }

        this.newWindow = (Window)dialog;
    }
```

ShowDialog:

```
public bool? ShowDialog()
    {
        if (this.newWindow == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        bool? result = this.newWindow.ShowDialog();

        this.newWindow = null;

        return result;
    }
```

Of course you need to add private field newWindow (type Window) in dialog service class. Now this allows you to get view instance in dialogService when calling PrepareDialog and after calling PrepareDialog you can apply changes to ViewModel's dialog service and then, at the end, call ShowDialog

Comment: This is as good solution as any! You should probably build upon this and not take a dependency towards MvvmDialogs since you have full control over the code you write yourself. Best of lucks going forward!